# No Visual Studio 2013 settings migrated to Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, migration, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn135229.aspx), when I have Visual Studio 2013 installed and I install Visual Studio 2015, my settings are migrated (I use the same account as well).

> Settings are not synchronized between Visual Studio 2013 and Visual
>   Studio 2015. The first time you open Visual Studio 2015, your settings
>   from Visual Studio 2013 are migrated, but they cannot be migrated back
>   to Visual Studio 2013 after that.

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 but I didn't have any chance to request the migration.

They look very differently now:

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Is there any tool to *force the migration*?

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I have used the **Import and Export Settings...** in the Tools menu.